# Mostrar en que línea se ha ejecutado un echo

Tags: php

Muchas veces tengo que tratar con ficheros muy grandes de código y para no tener que buscar muchas cosas cuando hago debug, me vendría muy bien saber en que línea se ha ejecutado por ejemplo un echo o capturar errores.

Esta función me pareció verla hace años y creo que era propia de PHP, era algo así:

```
.256  ....
.257  $linea = capturoEstaPosicion();
.258 
.259  echo "la posición es $linea"; // la posición es 257
```

Comment: para mostrar una variable tienes que sacarla de la string, `echo "la posición es " . $linea;`

Comment: Cuando son dobles comillas no hace falta sacarla fuera

Comment: Quizá lo que buscas es algo como [**`debug_backtrace()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace.php) o bien [**`debug_print_backtrace()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-print-backtrace.php). Creo que con eso, aplicándolo a tu contexto, obtendrás lo que necesitas.

Comment: Al final con la constante ```__LINE__``` me es suficiente, pero tomo nota de estas funciones que me pueden valer para hacer trazas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay una constante predefinida llamada `__LINE__` cuyo valor es el número de la línea donde se use:

```
echo "la posición es " . __LINE__;
```

> https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php